# Maven deploy in Jenkins docker pipeline cannot upload to AWS CodeArtifact - 401 cannot authenticate

Tags: maven, jenkins, devops, aws-codeartifact

What i'm trying to achieve is a declarative pipeline in Jenkins that runs in a docker image. The purpose is to compile a simple java springboot app with maven then do "mvn deploy" to AWS CodeArtifact for safekeeping.

Problem is that it works outside of container (on my machine) but in container the same exact thing does not work. What does not work is the upload to the repository, the build runs fine if i don't try to upload.

I have made pom.xml file, settings.xml, Dockerfile and a Jenkins file. They seem correct but something is definetly off.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.1.1:deploy (default-deploy) on project utils-library: Failed to retrieve remote metadata **domain**:utils-library:0.0.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata **domain**:utils-library:0.0.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to **snapshots** (https://**redacted**.d.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/maven/**my-snapshots**/): authentication failed for https://**redacted**.d.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/maven/my-snapshots/**redacted**/utils-library/0.0.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, status: 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
```

How i setuped this is like this:

i have the pom.xml file that has all the things it needs to build

```
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>**releases**</id>
            <name>**releases**</name>
            <url>https://**redacted**.d.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/maven/**my-releases**/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>**snapshots**</id>
            <name>**snapshots**</name>
            <url>https://**redacted**.d.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/maven/**my-snapshots**/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

The bold parts are the ones provided by AWS in the GUI when you click on connection instructions.

settings.xml

```
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>**releases**</id>
            <username>aws</username>
            <password>${env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN}</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>**snapshots**</id>
            <username>aws</username>
            <password>${env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN}</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

jenkins file is as followd

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile {
            label 'docker'
            args '-v /jenkins/docker/repo:/root/.m2'
        }
    }
    environment {
        CREDENTIALS_ID = 'AWS-Jenkins-User'
    }
    stages {
        stage('AWS CodeArtifact Login') {
            steps {
                script{
                    withCredentials([usernamePassword(
                        credentialsId: CREDENTIALS_ID,
                        passwordVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
                        usernameVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
                    )]) {
                        CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN = sh(
                            returnStdout: true,
                            script: 'aws codeartifact get-authorization-token \
                            --domain **domain** \
                            --domain-owner **1234** \
                            --region eu-central-1 \
                            --query authorizationToken \
                            --output text \
                            --duration-seconds 900'
                        ).trim()
                    }
                    echo CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN
                    git(
                        url: "git@bitbucket.org:domain/repo.git",
                        branch: "test",
                        changelog: true,
                        poll: true
                    )
                    sh '''
                    mvn --version
                    mvn deploy -s settings.xml
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Docker image is very simple, i just add aws cli to it.

```
FROM maven:3.8.6-openjdk-11

RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" 
RUN unzip awscliv2.zip
RUN ./aws/install
RUN which aws
RUN aws --version
COPY settings.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/
```

i've done probably 100 builds so far changing environment variables and trying different docker images. i do require jdk11 and maven 3.8.6 is fine

The result is every time 401 unauthorized when trying to upload it to the repo. Any reason why this would not work?

Comment: 401 sounds like our credentials are wrong

Answer (score 0):

After some more debugging i found out that the environment variable was not used at all.

If it is declared as above, it will not work with Maven but will however work with curl (you can use curl to upload too).

However the variable is not used by mvn because reasons i do not know.

The solution is to declare CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN like this:

```
env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN = sh (...)
```

Leaving this here for someone that has this issue like me and is pulling his hair out.